# How to annotate the type of a decorator of an async function in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, mypy

I'd like to write a decorator for an async function.  How can I annotate the type of the decorator definition?

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```py
from typing import TypeVar # will Awaitable help?
AsyncFn = TypeVar('AsyncFn') # how to narrow this type definition down to async functions?

def my_decorator(to_decorate: AsyncFn) -> AsyncFn:
    async def decorated(*args, **kwargs): # mypy keeps saying "Function is missing a type"
       return await to_decorate(*args, **kwargs)

@my_decorator
async def foo(bar: int) -> str:
    return f"async: {bar}"

@my_decorator
async def quux(spam: str, **eggs: str) -> None:
    return

foo(1) # should check
foo("baz") # mypy should yell
quux("spam") # should check
quux(1) # mypy should complain
quux(spam="lovely", eggs="plentiful") # ok
quux(spam=1, eggs=0) # mypy should throw a fit
```

Comment: I've never tried this, but I believe [`Coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Coroutine) is appropriate.

Comment: Seems right; when I `reveal_type(my_async_fn)` I get something like `def (bar: builtins.str) -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, builtins.int]`.

Comment: A closer reading of https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators indicates that the inner function can be typed as anything, so long as it's cast to the type of the input function.

Answer (score 9):

An `async` function is a function that returns an `Awaitable`.

With `ParamSpec` introduced in Python 3.10 the complete type annotations for a decorator for an `async` function is:

```
from typing import Awaitable, Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")


def decorator(fn: Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]:
    async def decorated(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return await fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

In Python 3.7 `ParamSpec` can be imported from [**typing_extensions**](https://github.com/python/typing/tree/master/typing_extensions).